# split into multilple column based on condition

Tags: postgresql, split

I have a column having 4000 records in postgres which i need to split into multiple columns based on condition that greatest number should be in col1,smaller in col2 and smallest in col3.col type is text
given column is like this

```
values
30-20/0.5
20/0.55
30/0.5
30-20/0.5
30/0.55
```

required output should be like this

```
 values val1  val2
 30     20    0.5
 20     0.55   0
 30     20    0.5
 30     0.55    0
```

I have tried split _part but it is not giving desired result.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=773eda2265e2d10d1cd59d6c3c17669e)

```
SELECT
    a[1] as col1,
    a[2] as col2,
    COALESCE(a[3], 0) as col3
FROM (
    SELECT
        (regexp_split_to_array(values, '[-/]'))::decimal[] as a
    FROM
        mytable
) s
```

1. `regexp_split_to_array` splits the string with help of the given delimiter. In this case `-` or `/`
2. Optional: `(array)::decimal[]` converts the string array to numeral array
3. `a[X]` gives the X-th element of the array
4. `COALESCE(a[3], 0)` gives out `0` if a third part does not exists (instead of `null`)

Comment: your  solution really worked.... but how can I update the table so that it store the changes

Comment: @ S-Man when i try to update it give me error for SELECT and if replace SELECT with SET i got error for 'as'

Comment: I updated is as   update mytable
SET
col1 = a[1],
col2 = COALESCE (a[2],0) ,
col3 = COALESCE(a[3], 0) 
FROM (
    SELECT
        (regexp_split_to_array(values, '[-/]'))::decimal[] as a
    FROM
        mytable
) s                       but it is taking 2 min to update. and then in col2 it is just adding 0.5 and in col3 as 0

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is split by hyphen and slash you could use a regular expression with regex_split_to array (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.9.7.2.2.29.1.1) like so

```
SELECT
    split.array[1] as col1,
    split.array[2] as col2,
    split.array[3] as col3
FROM (
    SELECT regexp_split_to_array('30-20/0.5', '-|\/') AS array
) AS split;
```

Just replace the string with a query to your table & column.

In order to sort the array you will need to create a custom function to sort the array like so.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sort_desc(ANYARRAY)
RETURNS ANYARRAY LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT ARRAY(
    SELECT $1[s.i] AS col
    FROM generate_series(array_lower($1,1), array_upper($1,1)) AS s(i)
    ORDER BY col DESC
);
$$;
```

So that you can get the ordering like so

```
SELECT
    split.array[1] as col1,
    split.array[2] as col2,
    split.array[3] as col3
FROM (
    SELECT array_sort_desc(regexp_split_to_array(your_column, '[-/]')::numeric[]) AS array
    FROM your_table
) AS split;
```

If there are less than 3 elements the rightmost items will be null.